# Why is Punisher wearing a white prison suit in Daredevil S02?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, costume, daredevil-tv

In Episode 08 and 09 of Season 02, in Netflix's *[Daredevil (TV Series 2015– )](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3322312/)*, we see Frank Castle (Punisher) in prison.

Why do all the other inmates, including Fisk, wear orange jumpsuits, while Frank Castle wears white?

I'm looking for an **in-universe explanation** (a red skull logo pops much better on white than it would on orange, so that makes sense as a meta, out-of-universe decision).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Prison uniforms can have different colors depending on different crimes/roles in the US.

> Different color designations are commonly used to indicate the status of the inmate. The uniforms may be in plain colors or horizontally striped black or white.
>
> In some cases the following color code is used
>
> - Dark red: supermax, or "worst of the worst"
> - Red: high-risk
> - **Orange: medium-risk**
> - Khaki or yellow: low-risk
> - **White: segregation unit or in specific cases, death row inmates**
> - Green or blue: low-risk inmates on work detail (e.g. kitchen, cleaning, laundry, mail, or other tasks)
> - Black/orange and white stripes: unspecific, commonly used for any status in some prisons
> - Pink: used for special punishment in some prisons
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prison_uniform#Color_designations)</sup>

As I recall, Fisk is a "white collar" criminal aand although he's crime boss he'd be considered Medium Risk

Frank Castle on the other hand, is a violent mass murderer.

Comment: *Season 2, Episode 9, Time code 00:01:27: "Newbies wear white." – Lettmannen *